# Camera component is not working as expected in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I have tried to implement `Camera` in my `react-native` application by using `react-native-camera`, However it doesn't seem like working. When i run `react-native run-android` blank white screen is appearing with out any errors. Here is my code,

```
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

<Camera
       style={Styles.preview}
       aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
       ref={cam => { this.camera = cam; }}
      />
const Styles = {
        preview: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            alignItems: 'center',
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permission so that the app can use the camera? If you haven't than you can set the permission as below:

### Android

To enable video recording feature you have to add the following code to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

### ios

Add the following permission in `/ios/yourProject/Info.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
  ...
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need your beautiful camera</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We're only saving to temp, promise</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

For full setup and code for camera app on ios follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/react-native-development/react-native-camera-app-with-live-preview-saturation-and-brightness-filters-d34535cc6d14). For more info on permission follow [this](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera#permissions).

Comment: I have given the permission as  shown above, But still I am able to see blank(white) screen only. No Progress. Could you suggest any alternative

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and discovered that I needed to manually set the header paths for iOS as described in the README [here](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera#ios).  Hope that helps you!